# Prevent formula references from updating when inserting a row

Tags: excel, vba, locking

I have this formula entered into my sheet

```
=COUNTIFS(Liste!B2:B504;"*";Liste!E2:E504;"*14*")
```

I also have a VBA script which automatically adds a row into Sheet[Liste]. This results in my formula ALSO updating — but I don't want that to happen.

How can I lock the field so it doesn't change the B2:B504 to B3:B505 whenever the VBA script runs?

Comment: In addition to the answer provided below.   This article might help.  [Abosolute References vs Relative References](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `$` before you reference the column and row, it will not change. For example:

```
=COUNTIFS(Liste!$B$2:$B$504;"*";Liste!$E$2:$E$504;"*14*")
```

Comment: Does this work? Certainly if I enter that formula in a worksheet then manually add a row anywhere before row 504 then the ranges change. In general absolute ranges don't fix ranges when rows are inserted/deleted. If you change the formula so that whole column references are used then that might give you what you need

Comment: @barryhoudini The formula wont change if you were to insert a row using absolute references.

Comment: OK, I'm just displaying my ignorance now, how do you insert a row using absolute references, is that an option only available in VBA?

Comment: @barryhoudini It's available in both VBA (by adding a `$` in a formula) as well as in a sheet. You can either manually add the `$` or you can hit F4 when typing the formula.

Comment: OK, sorry, ignore my last comment, I think we were at cross purposes. If I enter this formula in Sheet2 - `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,"x")` then in sheet1 I insert a row at row 1 the formula in sheet2 changes to this: =COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$101,"x") - having the $ signs doesn't prevent the range changing in this case.

Comment: I think the proposed solution needs a clarification. If the row is inserted above the range in the formula, then the the range in the formula will be updated (incremented). If the row is inserted below the start of the range, the start of the range is left unchanged but the end of the range is incremented

Answer (score 2):

you should use INDIRECT  when buidling your formula. 
ex.: =SUM(INDIRECT("A:A"))

this reads range inside indirect as text, so excel dosen't update the referenced range